# My original Java Font Program - Skewed when using different letters?

Tags: java, opengl, textures, lwjgl

The output of my font program is skewed. I'm pretty sure that the problem has to do with x and y, and how `printLetter()` uses them. It's possibly getting confused with multiple numbers for x and y? Please let me know if you need any additional code. 'findCoords' is called from inside the gameloop.

Additional background info:

It uses LWJGL and its OpenGL. the `+0.0769` and `+0.25` in `printLetter()` is how big each tile in the main image is(the main image that holds each of the letters is 78*24, and each letter is 6*6.), in proportion to 1, and xcoords[] and ycoords[] arrays of doubles: xcoords[] holds 0/13, 1/13, 2/13, 3/13, etc, and ycoords[] holds 0/4, 1/4, 2/4, 3/4, for `glTexCoord` has to be in proportion to 1. Here is a visual of the image that it's taking the texture coordinates from.

[image]

```
public void findCoords(String chars){
    int numChars = chars.length();
    for(int z = 0; z < numChars; z++){

        char ch = chars.charAt(z);
        int x;
        int y;

        switch(ch){
    //LETTERS
        case 'A': x= 0; y= 0; break; case 'N': x= 0; y= 1; break;
        case 'B': x= 1; y= 0; break; case 'O': x= 1; y= 1; break;
        case 'C': x= 2; y= 0; break; case 'P': x= 2; y= 1; break;
        case 'D': x= 3; y= 0; break; case 'Q': x= 3; y= 1; break;
        case 'E': x= 4; y= 0; break; case 'R': x= 4; y= 1; break;
        case 'F': x= 5; y= 0; break; case 'S': x= 5; y= 1; break;
        case 'G': x= 6; y= 0; break; case 'T': x= 6; y= 1; break;
        case 'H': x= 7; y= 0; break; case 'U': x= 7; y= 1; break;
        case 'I': x= 8; y= 0; break; case 'V': x= 8; y= 1; break;
        case 'J': x= 9; y= 0; break; case 'W': x= 9; y= 1; break;
        case 'K': x= 10; y= 0; break; case 'X': x= 10; y= 1; break;
        case 'L': x= 11; y= 0; break; case 'Y': x= 11; y= 1; break;
        case 'M': x= 12; y= 0; break; case 'Z': x= 12; y= 1; break;
    //NUMBERS
        case '0': x= 0; y= 2; break; case '5': x= 5; y= 2; break;
        case '1': x= 1; y= 2; break; case '6': x= 6; y= 2; break;
        case '2': x= 2; y= 2; break; case '7': x= 7; y= 2; break;
        case '3': x= 3; y= 2; break; case '8': x= 8; y= 2; break;
        case '4': x= 4; y= 2; break; case '9': x= 9; y= 2; break;
    //PUNCTUATION
        case '.': x= 10; y= 2; break; case '!': x= 12; y= 2; break;
        case ',': x= 11; y= 2; break;

        case '?': x= 0; y= 3; break; case '"': x= 2; y= 3; break;
        case ':': x= 1; y= 3; break; case ' ': x= 3; y= 3; break;

        default: x= 0; y= 3;
            }

            int offs = scale*z;
            printLetter(x, y, offs);

        }
    }
```

.

```
void printLetter(int x, int y, int offs){
    GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);

    GL11.glVertex2f(0+offs, scale);
    GL11.glTexCoord2d(xcoords[x]+0.0769, ycoords[y]+0.25);

    GL11.glVertex2f(scale+offs, scale);
    GL11.glTexCoord2d(xcoords[x]+0.0769, ycoords[y]);

    GL11.glVertex2f(scale+offs, 0);
    GL11.glTexCoord2d(xcoords[x], ycoords[y]);

    GL11.glVertex2f(0+offs, 0);
    GL11.glTexCoord2d(xcoords[x], ycoords[y]+0.25);

    GL11.glEnd();
    GL11.glFlush();
}
```

When `chars` is a single letter repeated, like `"AAAAA"` or `"BBBBBB"`, then there are no problems iwht the image. https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDwdr.png. However, when there are multiple letters in `chars` like `"AAABBB"` or `"ABABAB"` then the letters become skewed. The following image is what the output looks like when `chars` is

```
"AAABBB"
```

[image]

---

Before, the cases themselves called the print method with, for example

```
case 'A': printLetter(xcoord[0], ycoord[0], z)
```

I changed it to how it is now, to maybe make the program not as confused. Hopefully, even if it didn't fix the problem, it made it a bit easier to fix?

The problem may be because different letters will have different coordinates and that's messing up the way `printLetter()` is working? It's not in the cases, because I tested making two letters(A and F) have the same x and y, and made `chars` "AFAFAF", and there were no problems.

It also seems like, the further the letters are apart, the more screwed up they appear. Compare this "AAAZZZ" to the above "AAABBB":

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
GL11.glVertex2f(0+offs, scale);
GL11.glTexCoord2d(xcoords[x]+0.0769, ycoords[y]+0.25);

GL11.glVertex2f(scale+offs, scale);
GL11.glTexCoord2d(xcoords[x]+0.0769, ycoords[y]);

GL11.glVertex2f(scale+offs, 0);
GL11.glTexCoord2d(xcoords[x], ycoords[y]);

GL11.glVertex2f(0+offs, 0);
GL11.glTexCoord2d(xcoords[x], ycoords[y]+0.25);
```

These calls are backward. You should call `glTexCoord` before `glVertex`, not after. `glVertex` call finalizes the vertex and sends it to be drawn, so each texcoord is getting associated with the next vertex instead of the one you want.

Comment: I'll try this when I get back. Is this a solution to the problem or just a mistake I made?

Comment: @GlassZee I'm certain that this is causing your problem, the result looks exactly like what I would expect given the mistake.